# Shortcut Target is set to keyPath instead of parent file? (WIX documentation is wrong)

Tags: wix, shortcut

WIX [documentatino on Shortcut element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_shortcut.htm) says about Target attribute:

```
The value will be defaulted to the parent File when nested under a File element.
```

But the code

```
<Component Guid="MY_GUID" Id="MyAppComponent">
  <File Source="SomeDll.dll" Name="SomeDll.dll" Id="SomeDll.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
  <File Source="MyDll.exe" Name="MyDll.exe" Id="MyDll.exe" />
    <Shortcut Id="MyApp.Shortcut" Directory="ApplicationProgramMenuDir" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Name="MyApp" Icon="ProgramIcon.ico" Advertise="yes" />
  </File>
</Component>
```

does not work as expected - shortcut points to dll file and running it shows Windwos error message that it can't launch file with dll extention.

To fix that we need to make the only difference: set KeyPath="yes" attribute for exe file instead of dll:

```
<Component Guid="MY_GUID" Id="MyAppComponent">
  <File Source="SomeDll.dll" Name="SomeDll.dll" Id="SomeDll.dll"/>
  <File Source="MyDll.exe" Name="MyDll.exe" Id="MyDll.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
    <Shortcut Id="MyApp.Shortcut" Directory="ApplicationProgramMenuDir" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Name="MyApp" Icon="ProgramIcon.ico" Advertise="yes" />
  </File>
</Component>
```

So WIX documentation contains mistake? Target is set not to the parent File element, but to the ancestor's Component's KeyPath?

Or is it my mistake and something wrong with my code?

Comment: Not sure on the WiX front, so just pointing this out: your component is not structured as recommended by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368269.aspx #3 "Define a new component for every .exe, .dll, and .ocx file. Designate these files as the key path files of their components."

Comment: THat's a good recommendation. I already few times wanted to implement this but do not have time yet. Though this is not a requirement - only recommendation to ensure all files are correctly updated when installer Minor Upgrade or Patch logic is executed. I have Major upgrades so having all folder-files in single component didn't create any problems yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `<RegistryValue>` tag like this:

```
<Component Guid="MY_GUID" Id="MyAppComponent">
    <File Source="SomeDll.dll" Name="SomeDll.dll" Id="SomeDll.dll"/>
    <File Source="MyDll.exe" Name="MyDll.exe" Id="MyDll.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
        <Shortcut Id="MyApp.Shortcut" Directory="ApplicationProgramMenuDir" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Name="MyApp" Icon="ProgramIcon.ico" Advertise="yes" />
    </File>
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\setup" Name="Shortcut" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
</Component>
```

If your `InstallScope` is `perUser`, using `HKCU`

If your `InstallScope` is `perMachine`, using `HKLM`

Comment: I don't understand how RegistryValue should help in already working example? You just copied my working code sample. And I even don't understand what this RegistryValue is intended for??